# Understanding a proof in convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

[Theorem 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKeRJ.png)

I'm trying to understand this. In the last line, I understand that $P({\frac{1}{X_n} \geq 1 + \epsilon}$) goes to 0 when n goes to infinity. Since

$P({\frac{1}{X_n} \geq 1 + \epsilon}$) = $P({X_n} \leq \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon}$) = $P({X_n-1} \leq \frac{-\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon}$) , which goes to 0 since we are given $P(|X_n -1 | \geq \epsilon_0) \rightarrow 0$ for some $\epsilon_0 >0 $

But I don't understand $P({\frac{1}{X_n} \leq 0}$) and $P( 0 < \frac{1}{X_n} \leq 1 - \epsilon$) goes to zero. Need some help in this

Comment: $\frac1{X_n}\le0$ implies that $X_n\le0$, which implies that $X_n-1\le-1$, and
$0<\frac1{X_n}\le1-\epsilon$ implies that $X_n\ge\frac1{1-\epsilon}=1+\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$.